# Is there a way to avoid foreach with EF Core query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need advice on 2 things and below were db models and code
1.)Avoiding foreach loop with my entityframecore query
2.)Getting an error when using await keyword before context :- error invoice model was not awaitable

```
Public abstract class Customer {
Id  ,
Name,
Address , 
Collection <Invoice> Invoices 
}

Public class Invoice 
{
Id,
Date ,
Customer Id ,
Bill Amount
}
```

I need customer names who’s bill amount  was 500 , 200, 400 ( billmounts will change with every request)

```
List<string> Customername = new List<string>;

Foreach( var amount in bill amount) {
    Var result =  Context.Invoice
        .Include(Customer) 
        .where( i =>i.billamount == amount) 
        .select ( customer.name); 

     Customername.Add(result) 
}

return Customername;
```

PS:- Format was messing up after posting

Comment: To avoid a `foreach`, you can replace your `Where` predicate with `(i => BillAmounts.Contains(i.billamount))`, though I don't know if that will get evaluated on the server or (as you probably prefer) in the DB as SQL.

Comment: ...or whatever that collection of amounts is really called

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int[] billAmounts= billamount.ToArray(); // {500 , 200, 400 }

return  Context.Invoice
        .Where( i => billAmounts.Contains( i.billamount) )
        .Select (i=> i.Customer.name)
        .ToList();
```